# AppBar Image too dark

Tags: flutter, dart, png

I want to add a logo to the `AppBar`, but no matter if I put it as `leading` or `title`, it always looks darker than the original. The color of the AppBar is exactly #338585, which is also the background-color of my .png image when inside the `body` of a `Scaffold`.

Why do the images look so different?
Is there a BackdropFilter automatically applied to the AppBar, or could it be something with my file?

[image: These are all the same image files, but the ones in the AppBar appear darker]

Here's how to reproduce the issue (`createMaterialColor` generates a swatch from one color, but the AppBar is correct, so that's probably not the issue):

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: createMaterialColor(Color(0xFF338585)),
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: Image.asset('assets/logo.png'),
        ),
        body: Image.asset('assets/logo.png'),
      ),
    );
  }

  MaterialColor createMaterialColor(Color color) {
    List strengths = <double>[.05];
    final swatch = <int, Color>{};
    final int r = color.red, g = color.green, b = color.blue;

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
      strengths.add(0.1 * i);
    }
    strengths.forEach((strength) {
      final double ds = 0.5 - strength;
      swatch[(strength * 1000).round()] = Color.fromRGBO(
        r + ((ds < 0 ? r : (255 - r)) * ds).round(),
        g + ((ds < 0 ? g : (255 - g)) * ds).round(),
        b + ((ds < 0 ? b : (255 - b)) * ds).round(),
        1,
      );
    });
    return MaterialColor(color.value, swatch);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code as well, please?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the colors of the logo are semi-transparent and only appear as intended when it's used on a white background. The actual color values are not #338585, but #006666 instead.

Lesson learned: Don't use paint to check color values, when there might be transparency in an image.